# What does this auto layout error mean?

Tags: ios7, ios8, autolayout

I recently was trying to making my IOS 8 app built, with swift, become compatible with IOS 7 devices, but I've been running into some minor issues. I've fixed most of them, but I can't seem to find this error on the web or anything close to it. Can anyone explain how I might approach this issue and what this error exactly means?

```
2015-05-29 20:06:18.007 MyApp[553:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller. MyApp.homeInterfaceController's implementation needs to send -layoutSubviews to the view to invoke auto layout.'
```

Comment: Do you have a class called `homeInterfaceController` and does it have a `viewDidLayoutSubviews` implementation?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: So you are making a mistake in it.

Comment: @matt I'll give it a look. Everything seems to be fine with the app in IOS 8. Shall I post my viewdidlayout subviews code?

Comment: Ok, one minute. Thank you matt. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class called `homeInterfaceController` with a `viewDidLayoutSubviews` implementation. At the end of it, try calling

```
self.view.layoutSubviews()
```

It may be that it's better to say

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: That worked, but my view looks really ugly...I guess this means I have to make constraints programmatically, correct?

Comment: There are black borders showing, and everything is just misaligned. It looked fine in IOS 8 XD. So weird.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! I believe the black borders might be an auto layout issue. My auto layouts had been set on the storyboard in IOS 8, so I'm guessing I have to programmatically make them for IOS 7. The system needs me to wait 5 min to "check mark" your answer. Thank you so much Matt.

Comment: Good luck. This is why I don't try to make my apps backwards-compatible!

Comment: matt, one more question. Is it really worth it to make an app, in this day and age (not sure if IOS 9 beta is coming up soon), compatible with IOS 7. I seriously have not seen an app with it's description as: IOS 8 only. Almost every app I've see thus far is somewhat backwards compatible. My app runs beautifully on IOS 8 devices, I thought I might avoid angry reviews about compatibility, but honestly I just want to get my app out there for IOS 8.

Comment: I can't advise you on that! All my apps are always [latest iOS version] only each time I update them, but they don't make any money either. My personal view is: anyone who is sticking with iOS 7 must expect to be left behind; it isn't my job to placate them. :)